# OpenCV & Python : Printing the Red dot pixel value in HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

I am able to identify a circular object. How could i print the HoughCircle center point in pixels which is red in color. If there are two circles, how can i access by pixels ??

My code is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('STACK.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,1)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,3,100,param1=60,param2=80,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)                          
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),2)
cv2.imshow('Detected Circle',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How could i print the HoughCircle center point in pixels which is red in color"? Do you want to display the image original values for the circle center, or show de coordinates?

Comment: To show the coordinates of circle center @Eliezer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center pixel coordinates of your circles are stored inside the `circles` variable returned by `cv2.HoughLines`. This data structure provides the (X, Y) coordinates of your circles and their radius.

Looking at your code, each one of the `i` stores a circle.

If what you want is just show the circle center coordinates, you can print them on the standard output or show them in the image using the values inside array `i`:

```
for i in circles[0,:]:

    x = i[0]
    y = i[1]
    radius = i[2]

    # Draw text in image
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    text = '(' + str(x) + ',' + str(y) + ')'
    cv2.putText(cimg, text,(x + 5, y - 5), font, 0.5, (0, 125, 255), 2)

    # Print circle position
    print 'Circle with radius %.2f is at (%d, %d)' % (radius, x, y)

    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),2)
```